# Looking for a method for aligning objects (tattoos) within a photo

Tags: image-processing

We are looking to create a server side image processing for aligning & scaling the objects inside the photographs (tattoos).

I've looked into Hugin however it's struggles with photos with too much variation. I was wondering if there is a solution that we can train to look for the object in question and align to that object. Below is a link to sample images.

- Removed link *

Any insight, direction or otherwise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not share personal folders. I don't think that the cases with erased tatoos are doable.

Comment: this will need manual intervention, i.e. clicking/dragging control points until stuff looks good to a human.

Comment: Yves, Thanks makes sense 
Christoph,  Yeah i've a lot of success that way but looking to automate it.